# "Not enough input arguments" when trying to implement simple FOR loop using GPU

Tags: matlab, gpu

I'm trying to calculate the probability that a point (a nxn matrix) uniformly distributed in R^(n^2) exclusively has eigenvalues with negative real part, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in probability_n (line 4)
for i = 1:num_pts
```

Here is my code:

```
N = 10^2;
num_pts = 10^4;
n = 2;
n = n*ones(N,1,'gpuArray');

k = arrayfun(probability_n,n,num_pts);
```

and the function called is

```
function k = probability_n(n,num_pts)

    k = 0;
    for i = 1:num_pts
        R = reshape(randsphere(1,n^2,1),n,n);
        if all(real(eig(R))<0)
            k = k+1;
        end
    end

end

function P = randsphere(m,n,r)

    P = randn(m,n);
    s2 = sum(P.^2,2);
    P = P.*repmat(r*(gammainc(s2/2,n/2).^(1/n))./sqrt(s2),1,n);

end
```

Why is this happening? I suspect it is something very simple to do with a syntax error, since this is my first time trying to use my GPU for MATLAB. The GPU is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 580. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's best to test things in vanilla MATLAB (without GPU or parallel processing) if you experience issues to see if the issue is specific to the GPU or parallel processing or whether it's something else. If you do that, you'll see that your code still doesn't work.

This is because you need to pass a [**function handle**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) for `probability_n` to `arrayfun`, as you have it written, `probability_n` is implicitly called with no input arguments (you don't need the `()` to invoke a function). You receive the error you do when MATLAB tries to access `num_pts` from within `probability_n` and it hasn't been provided.

```
k = arrayfun(@probability_n, n, num_pts);
```

Note that passing the scalar `num_pts` as the third input only works when the first input to `arrayfun` is a `gpuarray` object. Otherwise, you'll want to create an anonymous function which passes `num_pts` to `probability_n`

Comment: Thanks, but now I get another error: `Error using gpuArray/arrayfun \\
Use of functional workspace is not supported.
For more information see Tips and Restrictions.` Is this because some built-in functions used in the `randsphere` function is not supported for GPU usage?

Comment: Thanks, but now I get `Function passed as first input argument contains unsupported or unknown
function 'reshape'.` I suspect it is because it is not supported in GPU-mode. I don't think `num_pts` being a scalar is a problem. From the [doc](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html): A = arrayfun(FUN,B,C,...) evaluates FUN using elements of arrays B, C, ... as input arguments with singleton expansion enabled. [...] The inputs B, C, ... must all have the same size or be scalar. Any scalar inputs are scalar expanded before being input to the function FUN.

Comment: @Lovsovs Yes, all functions you use within your function *must* be implemented for `gpuarray` objects since the data resides on the GPU. Also you're right about `arrayfun` on the GPU, this must have changed in a recent release. I have updated it